# Service not starting up after boot completed

Tags: android

I programmed a boot up receiver to start a service, but the service is not starting. I don't even think the broad cast receiver is receiving any intents.

I set the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

I declared the receiver in the manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".ServiceStarter">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Here is my broad cast receiver class. I'm not logging any output in this class after boot up.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class ServiceStarter extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent("com.prac.test.MyPersistingService");
        i.setClass(context, MyPersistingService.class);
        context.startService(i);

        Log.v("TAG","Broadcast received"); //Doesn't print anything
    }
}
```

Here is my service class. None of the toasts are displayed after boot up.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyPersistingService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service created!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();         //Doesn't show up
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          //Doesn't show up
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service started by user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //Doesn't show up
        Log.v("TAG", "Service started");
    }
}
```

Comment: check that the permission line of code is the first child of <manifest> not put within <application> </application>

Comment: Thanks, it's not. Could this be the problem? `Intent i = new Intent("com.prac.test.MyPersistingService");` com.prac.test. is the wrong package name...

Comment: it could be try correct the package and put the your log in the top on your onReceive

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26026471/1444496.

Comment: have you declared that service in manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<receiver android:name=".ServiceStarter" android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

if still dosn't work please try this

```
 <receiver
    android:name=".ServiceStarter"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />    
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Good luck

Comment: use the adb command - am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED instead of reboot phone each time

Comment: hi, i am curious about your question did the answer provided worked for you ?

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that your service is starting up, but is being killed off before it can do anything meaningful. Try acquiring a [partial wake lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) - Mark Murphy has written a [handy set of classes](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) just for that purpose.